# IP addressing error with docker with docker-compose

Tags: docker, docker-compose, bridge

I have mounted two identical docker on two ubuntu vps with docker-compose.
The concern is that the first one works well, and the pilces dialogue between it, the second one not.
What I see is that the ip set by default in 1 / is 172.X.X.X and the one set in 2 / is 192.X.X.X.
I am on virgin vps, no particular configuration file ... but I do not see how this is possible.
Here is the docker-compose

```
version: '2.4'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine



 db:
    image: mariadb:10.5
    working_dir: /application
    command: [mysqld, --character-set-server=utf8mb4, --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci, --innodb-file-format=Barracuda, --innodb-large-prefix=1, --innodb-file-per-table=1]
    volumes:
      - pimcore-demo-database:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=ROOT
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=pimcore
      - MYSQL_USER=pimcore
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=pimcore

  php:
    image: pimcore/pimcore:PHP8.0-apache
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html:cached
    ports:
     - 80:80
     - 443:443
    environment:
     - APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/html/public

  php-debug:
    image: pimcore/pimcore:PHP8.0-apache-debug
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html:cached
    ports:
     - 88:80
    environment:
      - PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=localhost"
      - APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/html/public

volumes:
  pimcore-demo-database:
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Why do the specific IP addresses matter?  In general, Docker will assign the IP addresses itself, and arrange things so the Compose service names are usable as the host names; you don't usually need to look at what exactly the addresses are.

Comment: Indeed, the problem is that the docker is not accessible from the outside, and the Php brick cannot therefore dialogue with the db. So I compare the same installs on another vps and that's what I noticed as a difference. So why does docker automatically assign an unreachable ip?

Answer (score 0):

Try to add networking config inside your compose yml to use specific IPs, like following:

more infos on https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#use-a-pre-existing-network

```
version: '2.4'
services:
  redis:
    image: redis:alpine

 db:
    image: mariadb:10.5
    working_dir: /application
    command: [mysqld, --character-set-server=utf8mb4, --collation-server=utf8mb4_unicode_ci, --innodb-file-format=Barracuda, --innodb-large-prefix=1, --innodb-file-per-table=1]
    volumes:
      - pimcore-demo-database:/var/lib/mysql
    environment:
      - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=ROOT
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=pimcore
      - MYSQL_USER=pimcore
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=pimcore
    networks:           # <-- Add this line
      - you_own_network # <-- Add this line

  php:
    image: pimcore/pimcore:PHP8.0-apache
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html:cached
    ports:
     - 80:80
     - 443:443
    environment:
     - APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/html/public
    networks:           # <-- Add this line
      - you_own_network # <-- Add this line

  php-debug:
    image: pimcore/pimcore:PHP8.0-apache-debug
    volumes:
      - .:/var/www/html:cached
    ports:
     - 88:80
    environment:
      - PHP_IDE_CONFIG="serverName=localhost"
      - APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/html/public
    networks:           # <-- Add this line
      - you_own_network # <-- Add this line

volumes:
  pimcore-demo-database:

networks:               # <-- Add this block
  you_own_network:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.123.123.0/24
```

Comment: (If you name the custom network `default`, [it sets configuration for the network Compose creates for you](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#configure-the-default-network) and you don't need to add `networks:` blocks to each service.)

Comment: Sorry that still doesn't work. Indeed, the problem is that the docker is not accessible from the outside, and the Php brick cannot therefore dialogue with the db. So I compare the same installs on another vps and that's what I noticed as a difference. So why does docker automatically assign an unreachable ip? Or why by default my docker is not accessible?

Answer (score 0):

Ok solution :

```
sudo snap remove docker
sudo rm -R /var/lib/docker
sudo apt-get remove docker docker-engine docker.io
sudo apt-get update
https://doc.ubuntu-fr.org/docker
systemctl start docker
```